# Sherlock and Valid String hackerank challenge

Tags: javascript, string

I tried to solve this specific challenge in Hackerank and I can't pass all the test cases.
2 is the minimum number of removals required to make it a valid string. It can be done in following two ways:

input = aabbcd...

Sample Output must be no....

Explanation

Remove c and d to get aabb. 
Or remove a and b to get abcd.

here is my code:

```
function processData(input) {
    //Enter your code here
   var unique = "";
    var counter = 0;
    var different ="";
  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input.lastIndexOf(input[i]) == input.indexOf(input[i])) {
      unique += input[i];

    }counter ++;
  var count1 = (input.match(/input[i]/) || []).length;
  }
    if (counter <= 1)
    {
        console.log("YES");
    }
    else if (counter > 1){
        console.log("NO"); 
    }
    //console.log(count1);
    //console.log(unique);
}
```

Comment: what does mean *to make it a valid string* in your case?

Comment: Your question does not give me enough information to understand what you're trying to do. Why are `aabb` and `abcd` "valid" strings? Why is `aabbcd` not a valid string?

Comment: A "valid" string is a string  S such that for all distinct characters in  S each such character occurs the same number of times in S.

For example, aabb is a valid string because the frequency of both characters a and b is 2, whereas aabbc is not a valid string because the frequency of characters a, b, and c is not the same.

Watson gives a string S to Sherlock and asks him to remove some characters from the string such that the new string is a "valid" string.

Sherlock wants to know from you if it's possible to be done with less than or equal to one removal.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithms is failing because your solution is not solving the problem.
Your final check to see whether the String is acceptable or not uses counter

```
  if (counter <= 1)
    {
        console.log("YES");
    }
    else if (counter > 1){
        console.log("NO"); 
    }
```

However counter is incremented everytime your for loop runs. This means your solutions is only passing the tests that resolve to "NO" by default.

Also your created a variable called different which you never used and both unique and count1 are assigned values but never used afterwards.

Your algorithm should check the frequency of  each string and see if they are the same (or a most different by 1) for each string.Your algorithm only checks for uniqueness of a letter. I would suggest counting the occurence ofeach letter using

```
input.match(/input[i]/).length;
```

and the comparing the frequencies

Comment: Here is the frequency:

Comment: var freq = {};
     for (var i=0; i<input.length;i++) {
var character = input.charAt(i);
         
         if (freq[character]) {
           freq[character]++;
        } else {
           freq[character] = 1;
        }
    
    
     }

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. Points to remember
1. Make sure you trim else your get escape \n as part of input.
2. Count occurrences of chars.
3. map char count to their occurrence.
4. Now check if occurrence is 1 => valid else if 2 make sure you check the at least one occurrence count is 1 ex: aabbcd c and d occurs 2 times and both have char count as 1 so he has to remove both c and d.

**Note:**  Not clarified in problem same char can be removed more than once and it still can be considered as one removal ex: aabbcccc I have 4 c's but I can use one operation to remove 2 C's to make it valid string aabbcc.

```
var bIsValidString = false;
var oCharMapCount = input.trim().split("").reduce((acc, val) => {
    if (acc[val]) {
        acc[val] += 1;
    }
    else {
        acc[val] = 1;
    }
    return acc;
}, {});
var oCharOccuranceMap = {}; 
for(let key in oCharMapCount) {
    if (oCharOccuranceMap[oCharMapCount[key]]) {
        oCharOccuranceMap[oCharMapCount[key]] += 1;
    }
    else {
        oCharOccuranceMap[oCharMapCount[key]] = 1;
    }
}
var iCharOccurances = (Object.keys(oCharOccuranceMap) || []).length;

if (iCharOccurances === 1) {
    bIsValidString = true;
}
else if (iCharOccurances === 2) {
    for (let iCharCountOccurance in oCharOccuranceMap) {
        if (oCharOccuranceMap[iCharCountOccurance] === 1) {
            bIsValidString = true;
        }
    }
}
else {
    bIsValidString = false;
}

(bIsValidString) ? console.log("YES") : console.log("NO");
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few iterations with 2 test cases failing, i finally came up with the correct solution below.

```
//create histogram to count occurances of each char in string
let chars               = s.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default:0] += 1 }

//create set for occurances to determine the number of different occurances found
let valueSet:Set<Int> = Set(chars.values)
var isValid = false

//if all chars have same occurrance
if valueSet.count == 1 {
    isValid = true
}
//if there are more than two different occurance counts
else if valueSet.count > 2 {
    isValid = false
} 
//check different frequencies counts
else {
    
    let freq1 = valueSet.min()!
    let freq2 = valueSet.max()!
    
    var freq1Count = 0
    var freq2Count = 0
    
    //loop through all values to count the amount of times each different occurance count occur
    for value in chars.values {
        switch value {
        case freq1:
            freq1Count += 1
        default:
            freq2Count += 1
        }
    }
    
    //if either freq count is 1 and it that count only occurs once
    if (freq1 == 1 && freq1Count == 1) ||
       (freq2 == 1 && freq2Count == 1) {
        isValid = true
    }
    //if the difference between frequencies is one and there is only one of them
    else if abs(freq1 - freq2) == 1 && (freq1Count == 1 || freq2Count == 1) {
        isValid = true
    }
    else {
        isValid = false
    }
}

return isValid ? "YES" : "NO"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried and solved it using below method :-

1. First take the count of frequency of all element in the string, i stored it in map `freq_count` against a key value pair, with key being character in string and value being the frequency up to that particular iteration.
2. I then only captured and stored frequency of all characters in strings in a vector `count` as we are interested to see based on number of occurrence if it could be converted to a valid string or not.
3. I sorted the vector `count` which makes my life easy to compare if all frequencies are same and if not whether a character with frequency as 1 or frequency one greater than all the other characters exist.

Note string is valid string:-

1. If all elements have same frequency.
2. If all index from `index 0 to size - 2` have frequency say `f` while index at `size-1` have frequency `f+1`. Note `count` is sorted and hence `f+1`
3. If all index from `index 1 to size - 1` have frequency say `f` while index at `0` has frequency 1. Note if it has frequency 1 it can be deleted then all remaining index will have frequency `f`

   ```
   string isValid(string s) 
   {
   std::map<char,int> freq_count;
   for(auto ele: s)
   {
       freq_count[ele] += 1;
   }

   if (freq_count.size() == 1)
       return "YES";

   if(freq_count.size() == 2)
   {
       if( (freq_count[s[0]] == freq_count[s[1]] ) || ( abs((freq_count[s[0]] - freq_count[s[1]] )) == 1 ) ) 
       return "YES";
       else
       return "NO";

   }
   std::vector<int> count;
   for(auto ele: freq_count)
   {
       count.push_back( ele.second );
   }
   std::sort(begin(count),end(count));
   if( count[0] == count[count.size()-1])
       return "YES";
   else  if (( count[0] == count[count.size()-2] ) && ((( count[0] - count[count.size()-1]) == -1 ) ))
   {   
       // if all elements other than last have same frequency count the two way for string to be valid is that  last element either has size 1 greater than all other element and hence check for -1 or or it has just 1 element which would remove existence of that element. Ideally just 1 element is not possible as this is sorted array 
       return "YES";
   }
   else  if (( count[1] == count[count.size()-1] ) && ( count[0] ==1 ))
   { 
       // if all elements other than first have same frequency count the two way for string to be valid is that  first element either has size 1 greater which is not possible as it is sorted .So only way is that the first index 1 as frequency and hence if element with 1 frequency when removed would have all other elements with same frequency remaining.  

       return "YES";
   }
   else
   {
       return "NO";
   }
   }
   ```

Note ideally one could have used the array instead of vector and do more optimization here, but for me this code passed all the test cases.